# Get a list of pics a user likes on Instagram

Tags: api, social-networking, instagram

is there a way to get a list (ideally XML or Json) of what pictures a specific user likes on Instagram? 
I had a look at the Instagram APIs but there's nothing like this. This would be have the same informations I can see in the News => Following menu but not limited to few hours.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for accessing other user's likes, you can only get logged-in user's likes using this endpoint: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/